# How to apply an ICC profile to an image/cam-capture?

Tags: python, opencv, colors, color-profile, color-management

I have taken photos of different objects in fluorescent white light (CRT) with FireFly MV CMOS camera, and have colour corrected them and made an ICC profile from it. Now I want to apply this to the camera capture in Python program (preferably using OpenCV, because that is all I presently know). How do I do this, so that I get colour corrected images when I capture from that camera in the same lighting condition? Thanks in advance!

If ICC profiles is not the right way to go about it, and something else makes it Python-friendly, please do suggest.